# Tanuki service-wrapper application works in console, fails as service with 1053

Tags: java, java-service-wrapper

I'm trying to get a one-jar java application to run as a service using the Tanuki java service-wrapper. Supposedly I have the application configured correctly, because when I run it in a cmd-prompt it runs fine. However after installing it as a service (using sc create Name binPath= path\to\executable) the service fails with:
**"Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion".**

This is my wrapper config:

```
#********************************************************************
# Wrapper License Properties (Ignored by Community Edition)
#********************************************************************
# Include file problems can be debugged by removing the first '#'
#  from the following line:
##include.debug
#include ../conf/wrapper-license.conf
#include ../conf/wrapper-license-%WRAPPER_HOST_NAME%.conf

#********************************************************************
# Wrapper Java Properties
#********************************************************************
# Java Application
wrapper.java.command=C:\YmorAgent\YmorAgentParser\jre1.7.0_25_x86\bin\java.exe

# Tell the Wrapper to log the full generated Java command line.
#wrapper.java.command.loglevel=INFO

# Java Main class.  This class must implement the WrapperListener interface
#  or guarantee that the WrapperManager class is initialized.  Helper
#  classes are provided to do this for you.  See the Integration section
#  of the documentation for details.
wrapper.java.mainclass=org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp


# Java Classpath (include wrapper.jar)  Add class path elements as
#  needed starting from 1a
wrapper.java.classpath.1=C:\YmorAgent\YmorAgentParser\wrapper.jar
wrapper.java.classpath.2=C:\YmorAgent\YmorAgentParser\YmorAgentParser.jar

# Java Library Path (location of Wrapper.DLL or libwrapper.so)
wrapper.java.library.path.1=C:\YmorAgent\YmorAgentParser

# Java Bits.  On applicable platforms, tells the JVM to run in 32 or 64-bit mode.
wrapper.java.additional.auto_bits=TRUE

# Java Additional Parameters
wrapper.java.additional.1=-XX:MaxPermSize=128m

wrapper.java.additional.2=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=3344
wrapper.java.additional.3=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
wrapper.java.additional.4=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false

# Initial Java Heap Size (in MB)
wrapper.java.initmemory=150

# Maximum Java Heap Size (in MB)
wrapper.java.maxmemory=256

# Application parameters.  Add parameters as needed starting from 1
wrapper.app.parameter.1=com.simontuffs.onejar.Boot
wrapper.app.parameter.2=-config
wrapper.app.parameter.3=C:\YmorAgent\YmorAgentParser\config.properties

#********************************************************************
# Wrapper Logging Properties
#********************************************************************
# Enables Debug output from the Wrapper.
wrapper.debug=TRUE

# Format of output for the console.  (See docs for formats)
wrapper.console.format=PM

# Log Level for console output.  (See docs for log levels)
wrapper.console.loglevel=DEBUG

# Log file to use for wrapper output logging.
wrapper.logfile=C:\YmorAgent\Log\YmorAgentParser_wrapper.log

# Format of output for the log file.  (See docs for formats)
wrapper.logfile.format=LPTM

# Log Level for log file output.  (See docs for log levels)
wrapper.logfile.loglevel=INFO

# Maximum size that the log file will be allowed to grow to before
#  the log is rolled. Size is specified in bytes.  The default value
#  of 0, disables log rolling.  May abbreviate with the 'k' (kb) or
#  'm' (mb) suffix.  For example: 10m = 10 megabytes.
wrapper.logfile.maxsize=10M

# Maximum number of rolled log files which will be allowed before old
#  files are deleted.  The default value of 0 implies no limit.
wrapper.logfile.maxfiles=10m

# Log Level for sys/event log output.  (See docs for log levels)
wrapper.syslog.loglevel=NONE

#********************************************************************
# Wrapper General Properties
#********************************************************************
# Allow for the use of non-contiguous numbered properties
wrapper.ignore_sequence_gaps=TRUE

# Title to use when running as a console
wrapper.console.title=Test Wrapper Sample Application

#********************************************************************
# Wrapper Windows NT/2000/XP Service Properties
#********************************************************************
# WARNING - Do not modify any of these properties when an application
#  using this configuration file has been installed as a service.
#  Please uninstall the service before modifying this section.  The
#  service can then be reinstalled.

# Name of the service
wrapper.name=Incidentprocessing

# Display name of the service
wrapper.displayname=Ymonitor Incidentprocessing

# Description of the service
wrapper.description=Ymonitor Incidentprocessing

# Service dependencies.  Add dependencies as needed starting from 1
wrapper.ntservice.dependency.1=

# Mode in which the service is installed.  AUTO_START or DEMAND_START
wrapper.ntservice.starttype=AUTO_START

# Allow the service to interact with the desktop.
wrapper.ntservice.interactive=false
```

And this is my debug log:

```
WARN   | wrapper  | 2013/09/06 14:46:13 | Encountered an invalid numerical value for configuration property wrapper.logfile.maxfiles=10m.  Resolving to 10.
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2013/09/06 14:46:13 | active log file changed: C:\YmorAgent\Log\YmorAgentParser_wrapper.log
STATUS | wrapper  | 2013/09/06 14:46:13 | --> Wrapper Started as Console
WARN   | wrapper  | 2013/09/06 14:46:13 | Attempt to set the console title failed: The handle is invalid. (0x6)
STATUS | wrapper  | 2013/09/06 14:46:13 | Java Service Wrapper Community Edition 32-bit 3.5.20
STATUS | wrapper  | 2013/09/06 14:46:13 |   Copyright (C) 1999-2013 Tanuki Software, Ltd. All Rights Reserved.
STATUS | wrapper  | 2013/09/06 14:46:13 |     http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com
STATUS | wrapper  | 2013/09/06 14:46:13 | 
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2013/09/06 14:46:13 | Launching Startup thread.
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2013/09/06 14:46:13 | Startup thread started.
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2013/09/06 14:46:13 | Attempting to verify the binary signature.
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2013/09/06 14:46:13 | The file "C:\YmorAgent\YmorAgentParser.exe" is signed and the signature was verified.
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2013/09/06 14:46:13 |   Signer Certificate:
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2013/09/06 14:46:13 |     Serial Number: 
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2013/09/06 14:46:13 |       00 97 06 fe b5 6e 56 cc cb 66 3a bb 55 a7 a0 e4 76 
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2013/09/06 14:46:13 |     Issuer Name: UTN-USERFirst-Object
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2013/09/06 14:46:13 |     Subject Name: Tanuki Software Ltd.
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2013/09/06 14:46:13 |   TimeStamp Certificate:
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2013/09/06 14:46:13 |     Serial Number: 
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2013/09/06 14:46:13 |       47 8a 8e fb 59 e1 d8 3f 0c e1 42 d2 a2 87 07 be 
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2013/09/06 14:46:13 |     Issuer Name: UTN-USERFirst-Object
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2013/09/06 14:46:13 |     Subject Name: COMODO Time Stamping Signer
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2013/09/06 14:46:13 | 
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2013/09/06 14:46:13 | Startup thread stopped.
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2013/09/06 14:46:13 | Release time: 2013/06/25 00:00:00
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2013/09/06 14:46:13 | Build time:   2013/06/25 19:32:00
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2013/09/06 14:46:13 | Timezone:     W. Europe Standard Time (W. Europe Daylight Time) Offset: -3600, hasDaylight: 1
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2013/09/06 14:46:13 | Using tick timer.
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2013/09/06 14:46:13 | Current User: SYSTEM  Domain: NT AUTHORITY
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2013/09/06 14:46:13 | Operating System ID: Microsoft Windows Server 2008 Standard Edition Service Pack 1 (build 6001), 64-bit
INFO   | wrapper  | 2013/09/06 14:46:13 | 
INFO   | wrapper  | 2013/09/06 14:46:13 | Environment variables (Source | Name=Value) BEGIN:
INFO   | wrapper  | 2013/09/06 14:46:13 |   P---- | ALLUSERSPROFILE=C:\ProgramData
INFO   | wrapper  | 2013/09/06 14:46:13 |   P---- | APPDATA=C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Roaming
INFO   | wrapper  | 2013/09/06 14:46:13 |   P---- | AQtime8Install=C:\Program Files (x86)\SmartBear\AQtime 8
INFO   | wrapper  | 2013/09/06 14:46:13 |   P---- | CommonProgramFiles=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
INFO   | wrapper  | 2013/09/06 14:46:13 |   P---- | CommonProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
INFO   | wrapper  | 2013/09/06 14:46:13 |   P---- | CommonProgramW6432=C:\Program Files\Common Files
INFO   | wrapper  | 2013/09/06 14:46:13 |   P---- | COMPUTERNAME=DEV-TEST-YMGMT
INFO   | wrapper  | 2013/09/06 14:46:13 |   P---- | ComSpec=C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe
INFO   | wrapper  | 2013/09/06 14:46:13 |   P---- | FP_NO_HOST_CHECK=NO
INFO   | wrapper  | 2013/09/06 14:46:13 |   P---- | LOCALAPPDATA=C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local
INFO   | wrapper  | 2013/09/06 14:46:13 |   P---- | NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS=4
INFO   | wrapper  | 2013/09/06 14:46:13 |   P---- | OS=Windows_NT
INFO   | wrapper  | 2013/09/06 14:46:13 |   P---- | Path=C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\binn\;C:\cygwin\bin\;C:\Program Files (x86)\SlikSvn\bin;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Visual Leak Detector\bin\Win32;C:\Program Files (x86)\Visual Leak Detector\bin\Win64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Dr. Memory\bin;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
INFO   | wrapper  | 2013/09/06 14:46:13 |   P---- | PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
INFO   | wrapper  | 2013/09/06 14:46:13 |   P---- | PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=x86
INFO   | wrapper  | 2013/09/06 14:46:13 |   P---- | PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432=AMD64
INFO   | wrapper  | 2013/09/06 14:46:13 |   P---- | PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 15 Stepping 1, GenuineIntel
INFO   | wrapper  | 2013/09/06 14:46:13 |   P---- | PROCESSOR_LEVEL=6
INFO   | wrapper  | 2013/09/06 14:46:13 |   P---- | PROCESSOR_REVISION=0f01
INFO   | wrapper  | 2013/09/06 14:46:13 |   P---- | ProgramData=C:\ProgramData
INFO   | wrapper  | 2013/09/06 14:46:13 |   P---- | ProgramFiles=C:\Program Files (x86)
INFO   | wrapper  | 2013/09/06 14:46:13 |   P---- | ProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)
INFO   | wrapper  | 2013/09/06 14:46:13 |   P---- | ProgramW6432=C:\Program Files
INFO   | wrapper  | 2013/09/06 14:46:13 |   P---- | PSModulePath=C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\
INFO   | wrapper  | 2013/09/06 14:46:13 |   P---- | PUBLIC=C:\Users\Public
INFO   | wrapper  | 2013/09/06 14:46:13 |   P---- | SystemDrive=C:
INFO   | wrapper  | 2013/09/06 14:46:13 |   P---- | SystemRoot=C:\Windows
INFO   | wrapper  | 2013/09/06 14:46:13 |   P---- | TEMP=C:\Windows\TEMP
INFO   | wrapper  | 2013/09/06 14:46:13 |   P---- | TMP=C:\Windows\TEMP
INFO   | wrapper  | 2013/09/06 14:46:13 |   P---- | USERDOMAIN=YMOR
INFO   | wrapper  | 2013/09/06 14:46:13 |   P---- | USERNAME=DEV-TEST-YMGMT$
INFO   | wrapper  | 2013/09/06 14:46:13 |   P---- | USERPROFILE=C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile
INFO   | wrapper  | 2013/09/06 14:46:13 |   P---- | VS100COMNTOOLS=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\Tools\
INFO   | wrapper  | 2013/09/06 14:46:13 |   P---- | VS90COMNTOOLS=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\Tools\
INFO   | wrapper  | 2013/09/06 14:46:13 |   P---- | windir=C:\Windows
INFO   | wrapper  | 2013/09/06 14:46:13 |   ---W- | WRAPPER_ARCH=x86
INFO   | wrapper  | 2013/09/06 14:46:13 |   ---W- | WRAPPER_BIN_DIR=C:\YmorAgent
INFO   | wrapper  | 2013/09/06 14:46:13 |   ---W- | WRAPPER_BITS=32
INFO   | wrapper  | 2013/09/06 14:46:13 |   ---W- | WRAPPER_CONF_DIR=C:\YmorAgent
INFO   | wrapper  | 2013/09/06 14:46:13 |   ---W- | WRAPPER_FILE_SEPARATOR=\
INFO   | wrapper  | 2013/09/06 14:46:13 |   ---W- | WRAPPER_HOST_NAME=Dev-test-ymgmt
INFO   | wrapper  | 2013/09/06 14:46:13 |   ---W- | WRAPPER_HOSTNAME=Dev-test-ymgmt
INFO   | wrapper  | 2013/09/06 14:46:13 |   P--W- | WRAPPER_INIT_DIR=C:\Windows\system32
INFO   | wrapper  | 2013/09/06 14:46:13 |   ---W- | WRAPPER_LANG=en
INFO   | wrapper  | 2013/09/06 14:46:13 |   ---W- | WRAPPER_OS=windows
INFO   | wrapper  | 2013/09/06 14:46:13 |   ---W- | WRAPPER_PATH_SEPARATOR=;
INFO   | wrapper  | 2013/09/06 14:46:13 |   ---W- | WRAPPER_PID=2808
INFO   | wrapper  | 2013/09/06 14:46:13 |   ---W- | WRAPPER_WORKING_DIR=C:\YmorAgent
INFO   | wrapper  | 2013/09/06 14:46:13 | Environment variables END:
INFO   | wrapper  | 2013/09/06 14:46:13 | 
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2013/09/06 14:46:13 | Use tick timer mutex=FALSE
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2013/09/06 14:46:13 | Preparing to restart with mode 1.
DEBUG  | wrapperp | 2013/09/06 14:46:13 | server listening on port 32000.
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2013/09/06 14:46:13 | Magic number for file C:\YmorAgent\YmorAgentParser\jre1.7.0_25_x86\bin\java.exe: 0x4d5a9000
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2013/09/06 14:46:13 | Ping settings: wrapper.ping.interval=5, wrapper.ping.interval.logged=1, wrapper.ping.timeout=30
STATUS | wrapper  | 2013/09/06 14:46:13 | Launching a JVM...
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2013/09/06 14:46:13 | Command: "C:\YmorAgent\YmorAgentParser\jre1.7.0_25_x86\bin\java.exe" -XX:MaxPermSize=128m -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=3344 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Xms150m -Xmx256m -Djava.library.path="C:\YmorAgent\YmorAgentParser" -classpath "C:\YmorAgent\YmorAgentParser\wrapper.jar;C:\YmorAgent\YmorAgentParser\YmorAgentParser.jar" -Dwrapper.key="8qO0DGscK9na5LQV" -Dwrapper.port=32000 -Dwrapper.jvm.port.min=31000 -Dwrapper.jvm.port.max=31999 -Dwrapper.debug="TRUE" -Dwrapper.pid=2808 -Dwrapper.version="3.5.20" -Dwrapper.native_library="wrapper" -Dwrapper.arch="x86" -Dwrapper.cpu.timeout="10" -Dwrapper.jvmid=1 org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp com.simontuffs.onejar.Boot -config C:\YmorAgent\YmorAgentParser\config.properties
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2013/09/06 14:46:13 | JVM started (PID=4964)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/09/06 14:46:14 | WrapperManager Debug: WrapperManager class initialized by thread: main   Using classloader: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@62af46
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/09/06 14:46:14 | WrapperManager: Initializing...
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/09/06 14:46:14 | WrapperManager Debug: JVM #1
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/09/06 14:46:14 | WrapperManager Debug: Running a 32-bit JVM.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/09/06 14:46:14 | WrapperManager Debug: org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperManager package information:
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/09/06 14:46:14 | WrapperManager Debug:   Implementation Title: org.tanukisoftware.wrapper
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/09/06 14:46:14 | WrapperManager Debug:   Implementation Vendor: Tanuki Software, Ltd.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/09/06 14:46:14 | WrapperManager Debug:   Implementation Version: 3.5.20
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/09/06 14:46:14 | WrapperManager Debug:   Is Sealed?: False
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/09/06 14:46:14 | WrapperManager Debug: org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperManager protection domain:
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/09/06 14:46:14 | WrapperManager Debug:   Location: file:/C:/YmorAgent/YmorAgentParser/wrapper.jar
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/09/06 14:46:14 | WrapperManager Debug:     Size: 119,512
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/09/06 14:46:14 | WrapperManager Debug:     MD5: 65e3184ab1d7f7f97cd14270f80653b3
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/09/06 14:46:14 | WrapperManager Debug: Registering shutdown hook
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/09/06 14:46:14 | WrapperManager Debug: Using wrapper
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/09/06 14:46:14 | WrapperManager Debug: Registered MBean with Platform MBean Server: org.tanukisoftware.wrapper:type=WrapperManager
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/09/06 14:46:14 | WrapperManager Debug: Load native library.  There are multiple possible file names and the first to be found will be used.  Errors loading non-existing files is normal and is only a problem if they all fail.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/09/06 14:46:14 | WrapperManager Debug:   Attempt to load native library with name: wrapper-windows-x86-32.dll  Result: no wrapper-windows-x86-32 in java.library.path
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/09/06 14:46:14 | WrapperManager Debug:   Attempt to load native library with name: wrapper.dll  Result: Success!
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/09/06 14:46:14 | WrapperManager Debug:   Successfully loaded native library.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/09/06 14:46:14 | WrapperManager Debug: Loaded localized resources.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/09/06 14:46:14 | WrapperManager Debug: Calling native initialization method.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/09/06 14:46:14 | WrapperJNI Debug: Initializing WrapperManager native library.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/09/06 14:46:14 | WrapperJNI Debug: Java Executable: C:\YmorAgent\YmorAgentParser\jre1.7.0_25_x86\bin\java.exe
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/09/06 14:46:14 | WrapperJNI Debug: Native Library: C:\YmorAgent\YmorAgentParser\wrapper.dll
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/09/06 14:46:14 | WrapperJNI Debug: Windows version: 6.0.6001
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/09/06 14:46:14 | WrapperManager Debug: Java Version   : 1.7.0_25-b17 Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/09/06 14:46:14 | WrapperManager Debug: Java VM Vendor : Oracle Corporation
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/09/06 14:46:14 | WrapperManager Debug: OS Name        : Windows Server 2008
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/09/06 14:46:14 | WrapperManager Debug: OS Arch        : x86
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/09/06 14:46:14 | WrapperManager Debug: 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/09/06 14:46:14 | WrapperManager Debug: Startup runner thread started.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/09/06 14:46:14 | WrapperManager Debug: Control event monitor thread started.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/09/06 14:46:14 | WrapperManager Debug: WrapperManager.start(a org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp, args["-config", "C:\YmorAgent\YmorAgentParser\config.properties"]) called by thread: main
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/09/06 14:46:14 | WrapperManager Debug: Initial thread: main Priority: 5
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/09/06 14:46:14 | WrapperManager Debug: Communications runner thread started.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/09/06 14:46:14 | WrapperManager Debug: Open socket to wrapper...Wrapper-Connection
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/09/06 14:46:14 | WrapperManager Debug: Unable to open socket to Wrapper from port 31,000, already in use.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/09/06 14:46:14 | WrapperManager Debug: Opened Socket from 31,001 to 32,000
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/09/06 14:46:14 | WrapperManager Debug: Send a packet KEY : 8qO0DGscK9na5LQV
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/09/06 14:46:14 | WrapperManager Debug: handleBackend()
DEBUG  | wrapperp | 2013/09/06 14:46:14 | accepted a socket from 127.0.0.1 on port 31001
DEBUG  | wrapperp | 2013/09/06 14:46:14 | closing backend server.
DEBUG  | wrapperp | 2013/09/06 14:46:14 | read a packet KEY : 8qO0DGscK9na5LQV
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2013/09/06 14:46:14 | Got key from JVM: 8qO0DGscK9na5LQV
DEBUG  | wrapperp | 2013/09/06 14:46:14 | send a packet LOW_LOG_LEVEL : 1
DEBUG  | wrapperp | 2013/09/06 14:46:14 | send a packet LOGFILE : C:\YmorAgent\Log\YmorAgentParser_wrapper.log
DEBUG  | wrapperp | 2013/09/06 14:46:14 | send a packet PROPERTIES : (Property Values)
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2013/09/06 14:46:14 | Start Application.
DEBUG  | wrapperp | 2013/09/06 14:46:14 | send a packet START : start
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/09/06 14:46:14 | WrapperManager Debug: Received a packet LOW_LOG_LEVEL : 1
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/09/06 14:46:14 | WrapperManager Debug: LowLogLevel from Wrapper is 1
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/09/06 14:46:14 | WrapperManager Debug: Received a packet LOGFILE : C:\YmorAgent\Log\YmorAgentParser_wrapper.log
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/09/06 14:46:14 | WrapperManager Debug: Received a packet PROPERTIES : (Property Values)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/09/06 14:46:14 | WrapperManager Debug: Received a packet START : start
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/09/06 14:46:14 | WrapperManager Debug: Java temporary directory: C:\Windows\TEMP
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/09/06 14:46:14 | WrapperManager Debug: calling WrapperListener.start()
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/09/06 14:46:14 | WrapperManager Debug: WrapperListener.start runner thread started.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/09/06 14:46:14 | WrapperManager Debug: Application start main thread: WrapperListener_start_runner Priority: 5
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/09/06 14:46:14 | WrapperSimpleApp Debug: start(args) Will wait up to 2 seconds for the main method to complete.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/09/06 14:46:14 | WrapperSimpleApp Debug: invoking main method
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/09/06 14:46:15 | WrapperManager Debug: Send a packet START_PENDING : 5000
DEBUG  | wrapperp | 2013/09/06 14:46:15 | read a packet START_PENDING : 5000
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2013/09/06 14:46:15 | JVM signaled a start pending with waitHint of 5000 millis.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/09/06 14:46:16 | WrapperManager Debug: Send a packet START_PENDING : 5000
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/09/06 14:46:16 | WrapperSimpleApp Debug: start(args) end.  Main Completed=false, exitCode=null
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/09/06 14:46:16 | WrapperManager Debug: returned from WrapperListener.start()
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/09/06 14:46:16 | WrapperManager Debug: Send a packet STARTED : 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/09/06 14:46:16 | WrapperManager Debug: WrapperListener.start runner thread stopped.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/09/06 14:46:16 | WrapperManager Debug: Startup runner thread stopped.
DEBUG  | wrapperp | 2013/09/06 14:46:16 | read a packet START_PENDING : 5000
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2013/09/06 14:46:16 | JVM signaled a start pending with waitHint of 5000 millis.
DEBUG  | wrapperp | 2013/09/06 14:46:16 | read a packet STARTED : 
DEBUG  | wrapper  | 2013/09/06 14:46:16 | JVM signaled that it was started.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/09/06 14:46:16 | WrapperSimpleApp Debug: main method completed
DEBUG  | wrapperp | 2013/09/06 14:46:17 | send a packet PING : ping fffffe2b
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/09/06 14:46:17 | WrapperManager Debug: Received a packet PING : ping fffffe2b
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/09/06 14:46:17 | WrapperManager Debug: Send a packet PING : ping fffffe2b
DEBUG  | wrapperp | 2013/09/06 14:46:17 | read a packet PING : ping fffffe2b
DEBUG  | wrapperp | 2013/09/06 14:46:21 | send a packet PING : ping fffffe54
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/09/06 14:46:21 | WrapperManager Debug: Received a packet PING : ping fffffe54
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/09/06 14:46:21 | WrapperManager Debug: Send a packet PING : ping fffffe54
DEBUG  | wrapperp | 2013/09/06 14:46:21 | read a packet PING : ping fffffe54
DEBUG  | wrapperp | 2013/09/06 14:46:25 | send a packet PING : ping fffffe7d
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/09/06 14:46:25 | WrapperManager Debug: Received a packet PING : ping fffffe7d
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/09/06 14:46:25 | WrapperManager Debug: Send a packet PING : ping fffffe7d
DEBUG  | wrapperp | 2013/09/06 14:46:25 | read a packet PING : ping fffffe7d
DEBUG  | wrapperp | 2013/09/06 14:46:30 | send a packet PING : ping fffffea6
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/09/06 14:46:30 | WrapperManager Debug: Received a packet PING : ping fffffea6
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/09/06 14:46:30 | WrapperManager Debug: Send a packet PING : ping fffffea6
DEBUG  | wrapperp | 2013/09/06 14:46:30 | read a packet PING : ping fffffea6
DEBUG  | wrapperp | 2013/09/06 14:46:34 | send a packet PING : ping fffffecf
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/09/06 14:46:34 | WrapperManager Debug: Received a packet PING : ping fffffecf
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/09/06 14:46:34 | WrapperManager Debug: Send a packet PING : ping fffffecf
DEBUG  | wrapperp | 2013/09/06 14:46:34 | read a packet PING : ping fffffecf
DEBUG  | wrapperp | 2013/09/06 14:46:38 | send a packet PING : ping fffffef8
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/09/06 14:46:38 | WrapperManager Debug: Received a packet PING : ping fffffef8
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/09/06 14:46:38 | WrapperManager Debug: Send a packet PING : ping fffffef8
DEBUG  | wrapperp | 2013/09/06 14:46:38 | read a packet PING : ping fffffef8
DEBUG  | wrapperp | 2013/09/06 14:46:42 | send a packet PING : ping ffffff21
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/09/06 14:46:42 | WrapperManager Debug: Received a packet PING : ping ffffff21
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/09/06 14:46:42 | WrapperManager Debug: Send a packet PING : ping ffffff21
DEBUG  | wrapperp | 2013/09/06 14:46:42 | read a packet PING : ping ffffff21
```

I've tested this on:

- Windows Server 2008 64-bit
- Windows 7 Professional SP1 64-bit

Have I made a mistake in my config? Or is there anything else I can try?

Comment: have you tried with the  JavaExe freeware ? there is no config for working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what I did wrong. I created the service through the sc create command, rather than using the build in options of the java service wrapper executables. This resulted in the service wrapper executable not being able to start correctly, because of missing command-line parameters.

Comment: you can create the service with the sc create command manually and then add the java service option param using regedit